# Tensorflow architecture for pixel based image classification

Tags: image, tensorflow, classification, pixel, tflearn

I have an RGBI image including 4 bands and want to be able to classify image pixels using tensorflow and deep learning into two classes.
In the training data, each pixel is regarded an observation with 4 values/features as image intensity. I used the following function to create the network

```
def deep_learn(X,Y,X_test,Y_test):

    net = input_data(shape=[None, 1,4])
    net = tflearn.lstm(net, 128, return_seq=True)
    net = tflearn.lstm(net, 128)
    net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 2, activation='softmax')
    net = tflearn.regression(net, optimizer='adam',
                             loss='categorical_crossentropy', name="deep")
    model = tflearn.DNN(net, tensorboard_verbose=2)
    model.fit(X, Y, n_epoch=1, validation_set=0.1, show_metric=True,
              snapshot_step=100)
    # Save model when training is complete to a file
    model.save("deep")
    return model
```

but I got the following error

> ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (64, 4) for Tensor 'InputData/X:0', which has shape '(?, 1, 4)'

I don't know where the problem is. 
Is there any benefit in using Deep Neural Networks versus Random Forest for pixel-based classification?
and if yes, how can I do this using the above function.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to expand the dimensions of variable `X`, to account for the time step in the LSTM. Instead of directly passing `X`, use [`np.expand_dims`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html) like -

```
X = np.expand_dims(X, axis=1)
```

Comment: That solved my problem but I have another issue. After training the model, the result of  p.array(model.predict(x_test))  is 1 only. In one example where I have had 4 classes of object and I expected the result of that command to be a label between 2 and 5 but again the output of the prediction function is 1. Could that be a problem of training phase?

Comment: What's the output layer of your NN? It's best if you upvote / accept this answer and ask that in a new question as it's unrelated. Also, send me a link to the new question out here

Comment: Here is the link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41414305/wrong-output-of-prediction-function-in-tensorflow