# Wrong output of prediction function in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, classification, pixel, tflearn

I am going to perform pixel-based classification on an image. Here is the code I used for training the NN

```
net = input_data(shape=[None, 1,4])
net = tflearn.lstm(net, 128, return_seq=True)
net = tflearn.lstm(net, 128)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 1, activation='softmax')
net = tflearn.regression(net, optimizer='adam',
                         loss='categorical_crossentropy')
model = tflearn.DNN(net, tensorboard_verbose=2, checkpoint_path='model.tfl.ckpt')
X_train = np.expand_dims(X_train, axis=1)
model.fit(X_train, y_train, n_epoch=1, validation_set=0.1, show_metric=True,snapshot_step=100)
```

The problem is that after training the model, the result of p.array(model.predict(x_test)) is 1 only although I expected this to be either 2 or 3. In one example where I have had 4 classes of objects and I expected the result of that command to be a label between 2 and 5 (note:y_train has int values between 2 and 5) but again the output of the prediction function is 1. Could that be a problem of training phase?

Comment: You definitely need to increase `n_epoch`. I haven't used the `tf_learn` package, but how can you use `regression` when your problem is classification?

Comment: I am newbie and just wanted to have a few testing and just copied this code from TFlearn webpage at   https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/examples/images/rnn_pixels.py

Comment: Try increasing `n_epoch` to 5 or 10 and see if it helps? Are you consistently getting `1` across all test data?

Comment: yes, the output is 1 and it seems that either training and prediction isn't correct.

Comment: Have you copied the Github code exactly or is there a difference in the `input_data`?

Comment: I just changed the input data from input_data(shape=[None, 28, 28]) to input_data(shape=[None, 1,4]) because what I have got is a set of intensity values of 4 image bands and its corresponding label. So each image pixel is an object with 4 features/intensity values.

Comment: Are you still using  `tflearn.input_data()` or is this your custom function? I don't seem to understand what you hope to achieve. Each image is a `28*28` grid. If you hope to use 4 bands, you should use rows of length `28*28*4` since you have 4 times the features, not `4*1`. If you are using `tf_learn.input_data()`, I suspect this shape will give you random results. Could you update the question with your whole code?

Comment: I am using tflearn.input_data() so input_data isn't my custom function. Let's say I am using an image of 28*28*4 dimensions and I am going to use them for image-based classification. My understanding is that in this case I have 28* 28 rows and each row has 4 values? Is this assumption correct? I use the same way in other classification methods like Random Forest and the result is ok.

Comment: Why don't you try printing the shapes for `X_train` and `Y_train`?

Comment: X_train.shape --> (50484, 4) and y_train.shape --> (50484, 1)

Comment: From where are you fetching 4 channel data? I just read the code of `tflearn.datasets.mnist` and it doesn't seem to have 4 channel data. Also, you should definitely reshape your grid to `28*28*4`

Comment: I have my own 4 channel imagery data and don't use mnist data. Basically, I have digitised different areas as training area on the 4-channel image representing the objects of interest, lets say roads and buildings, and then I used pixels within those areas with each pixel having 4 values as training rows.

Comment: Please add your dataset specification in the question, it's completely unclear. Last question, do you wish to classify each pixel, or do you hope to classify images on a whole? My answer should help you in case you wish to classify images.

Comment: I want to be able to classify each pixel separately. Then I put them together through reshape to get the whole image. In the predicting phase, I can access each pixel as a row of 1*4 dimensions and would like to get the predicted value.

Answer (score 0):

The `None` parameter is used to denote *different* training examples. In your case, each image has a total of `28*28*4` parameters, due to the custom four channel dataset you are using.

To make this LSTM work, you should try to do the following -

```
X = np.reshape(X, (-1, 28, 28, 4))
testX = np.reshape(testX, (-1, 28, 28, 4))

net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 28, 28, 4])
```

Of course, *(this is very important)*, make sure that `reshape()` puts the four different channels corresponding to a single pixel in the last dimension of the numpy array, and the `28, 28` correspond to pixels in a single image.

---

In case your images don't have dimension `28*28`, adjust those parameters accordingly.

Comment: Not sure. I followed the example here https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/tutorials/intro/quickstart.md . In my case I need to change 6 to 4 as I have 4 features for each pixel. But again the prediction result is 1 all the time although I expect 1 and 2. 1 label corresponds to green pixels and 2 to brown pixels.